# sybase - fails to use index unless string is hard-coded

Tags: t-sql, database-performance, sap-ase

I'm using **Sybase 12.5.3 (ASE)**; I'm new to Sybase though I've worked with MSSQL pretty extensively. I'm running into a scenario where a stored procedure is really very slow. I've traced the issue to a single SELECT stmt for a relatively large table. Modifying that statement dramatically improves the performance of the procedure (and reverting it drastically slows it down; i.e., the SELECT stmt is definitely the culprit).

```
-- Sybase optimizes and uses multi-column index... fast!<br>
SELECT ID,status,dateTime
FROM myTable
WHERE status in ('NEW','SENT')
ORDER BY ID

-- Sybase does not use index and does very slow table scan<br>
SELECT ID,status,dateTime
FROM myTable
WHERE status in (select status from allowableStatusValues)
ORDER BY ID
```

The code above is an adapted/simplified version of the actual code. Note that I've already tried recompiling the procedure, updating statistics, etc.

I have no idea why Sybase ASE would choose an index only when strings are hard-coded and choose a table scan when choosing from another table. Someone please give me a clue, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.The issue here is poor coding.  In your release, poor code and poor table design are the main reasons (98%) the optimiser makes incorrect decisions (the two go hand-in-hand, I have not figured out the proportion of each).  Both:

```
    WHERE status IN ('NEW','SENT')
```

and

```
    WHERE status IN (SELECT status FROM allowableStatusValues)
```

are substandard, because in both cases they cause ASE to create a worktable for the contents between the brackets, which can easily be avoided (and all consequential issues avoided with it).  There is no possibility of statistics on a worktable, since the statistics on either t.status or s.status is missing (AdamH is correct re that point), it correctly chooses a table scan.

Subqueries have their place, but never as a substitute for a pure (the tables *are* related) join.  The corrections are:

```
    WHERE status = "NEW" OR status = "SENT"
```

and

```
    FROM  myTable t,
          allowableStatusValues s
    WHERE t.status = s.status
```

2.The statement

|*Now you don't have to add an index to get statistics on a column, but **it's probably the best way.***

is incorrect.  Never create Indices that you will not use.  If you want statistics updated on a column, simply

```
    UPDATE STATISTICS myTable (status)
```

3.It is important to ensure that you have current statistics on (a) all indexed columns and (b) all join columns.

4.Yes, there is no substitute for SHOWPLAN on every code segment that is intended for release, doubly so for any code with questionable performance. You can also `SET NOEXEC ON`, to avoid execution, eg. for large result sets.

Comment: Is it the same in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes it is.  Except: the value at (1) is 90%.  The stats are not nearly as good (detailed); and 2005 is more "sensitive" to stats problems.

Comment: A worktable could be created for both the join or the subquery method, it depends on factors other than the choice of subquery/join. However in this simple example I think that both the subquery and the join will produce the same query plan, it certainly does in my tests. There is a situation in which the subquery wins, and that's if the table allowableStatusValues (in this example) had duplicate values in the status column, the join method will not return what you expect.

Comment: @AdamH: 1. check your SHOWPLAN.  The only worktable here, is for the IN(); no worktable required for indices referenced.  What I did was avoid the IN, consciously.  2.  By my comment, I meant, note your incorrect advice re update stats via create index!!!

Comment: 1. I did check my queryplan, and for every example I tested if the subquery had a worktable so did the join, and if the subquery didn't have a worktable neither did the join. 2. Yes my advice taken on it's own is misleading. Managing your stats in ASE is a complex area in which you have to do much more work than in MSSQL for example.

Answer (score 2):

An index hint will work around it, but is probably not the solution.

Firstly I'd like to know if there is an index on allowableStatusValues.status, if there is then sybase will have stats on it and will have a good idea on the number of values in there. 
If not then the optimiser probably won't have a good idea how many different values Status may take. It's then having to make the assumption that you're going to be extracting almost all of the rows from myTable, and the best way of doing this is a table scan (if no covering index).

Now you don't have to add an index to get statistics on a column, but it's probably the best way.

If you do have an index on allowableStatusValues.status, then i'd wonder how good your stats are. Get yourself a copy of [sp__optdiag](http://www.teamsybase.net/kevin.sherlock/sps/mine/sp__optdiag_v1_9_4.txt). You probably also need to tune the values of "histogram tuning factor" and "number of histogram steps", increasing these slightly from the defaults will give you more detailed statistics which always helps the optimiser.

Comment: Please refer to my answer (I did not have enough points at the time to leave a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Does it still do a table scan if you replace the subquery with a join:

```
SELECT m.ID,m.status,m.dateTime 
FROM myTable m
JOIN allowableStatusValues a on m.status = a.status
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on experimental observations of how long a query takes to run, I would highly recommend getting Sybase to show you the execution plans for each query, for example:

```
SET showplan ON
GO

-- query/procedure call goes here
SELECT id, status, datetime
FROM myTable
WHERE status IN('NEW','SENT')
ORDER BY id
GO

SET showplan OFF
GO
```

With `SET showplan ON`, Sybase  generates execution plans for every statement it executes. These can be invaluable in helping to identify where queries are not making use of appropriate indexes. For stored procedures in Sybase, the execution plan for the entire procedure is generated when the stored procedure is first executed after being compiled.

If you post the plans for each of your queries we might be able to shed more light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, using an **index hint** resolves the issue (see the **(index myIndexName)** line below - re-written/simplififed code below:

```
-- using INDEX HINT
SELECT ID,status,dateTime 
FROM myTable (index myIndexName)
WHERE status in (select status from allowableStatusValues) 
ORDER BY ID
```

Weird that I **have** to use this technique to avoid a table scan, but there ya go.

Comment: For anyone else coming to this problem in the future, you do NOT have to use this technique to avoid a tablescan. The precise plan used depends on your data, and the statistics that sybase has available to help it make the decision. Unfortunately without further info from Garrett we'll never know why sybase was chosing this plan in this instance.
- Check your statistics, do you have any on the column in question? Are they up to date? Do you have enough histogram points in the stats? Is your data skewed? (ie select * from person where sex in ('m','f') )

Answer (score 0):

Garrett, by showing only the simplified code, you have likely stripped out exactly the information that would illuminate the source of the problem.

My first guess would be a type mismatch between allowableStatusValues.status and myTable.status.  However, that is not the only possibility.  As ninesided stated, the complete query plans (using showplan and fmtonly flags), as well as the actual table definitions and stored procedure source, is much more likely to produce a useful answer.